# Linux kernel: scatterlist maximum "length" allowed?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Having solved my Linux crypto example, and I can call the aead ciphers correctly, I have come across an interesting issue.

I define my scatterlists like:

```
struct scatterlist sg[2];
sg_init_table(sg, 2 );
sg_set_buf(&sg[0], address, 512);
sg_set_buf(&sg[1], mac, 16);
aead_request_set_crypt(req, sg, sg, 512, iv);
crypto_aead_encrypt(req);
```

and that works great. However, if you increase the buffer size from 512, to say, 131072, then it will "very often" panic.

```
 BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffeb04000cea80
 IP: [<ffffffff812f4880>] scatterwalk_done+0x50/0x60
```

Now, since all ciphers end up calling the scatterwalk_ functions, I *assume* it is a problem  with setting the sg->length to something large. Presumably so large it sometimes crosses over to the next page.

What is the proper thing to do here? Do I have to split it up into many scatterlists, making sure each one does not go over to the next page? That sounds like a hassle, or is there a function that does this for me? Or do I simply need to make sure each page is "available" ?

Comment: Don't you have to allocate memory for the buffers somehow?

Comment: The buffers are of course allocated outside of this scope. As one long contiguous block. I can write to the whole buffer without issues.

Comment: Damn, worse than that. I can put these lines in, between setting up the scatterlist, and before the call to crypto:

            broken = kmalloc(plainlen, GFP_KERNEL);
            if (broken) {
                scatterwalk_map_and_copy(broken, linux_plain,
                                     0, plainlen, 0);
                printk("spl-crypto: copy one.\n");
                kfree(broken);
            }
and likewise one for linux_cipher, and both scatterwalk calls work fine, crypto still panics. So it is a problem with crypto, not scatterlists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there were in fact 2 things bothering me here. The first one was that occasionally the memory handed to me was in fact from vmalloc() allocated memory. Which means I should use sg_set_page( , vmalloc_to_page() ) instead.

The second problem is that the scatterwalk functions are incorrect, it is easy to test, if you setup any cipher that also generates a mac, as a second buffer;

```
cipherout = kmalloc( size, ...
macout = kmalloc( maclen, ...
```

this will generally work, because new allocated memory is on page boundary. However, change it to;

```
 macout = kmalloc( maclen + 16, ...
 macout += 16;
```

All I do is allocate a larger buffer, then start the memory 16 bytes in. (+1024, or +3480, doesn't matter) This will make scatterwalk panic. There is a suggested patch on the linux-crypto mailing list, which is great for future, but does not help me right now. I need to make sure the mac address is aligned, and if not, allocate temporary buffer (which is small at least).

Comment: How can you know the source of a given buffer ? - By source I typically mean `vmalloc()` or `kmalloc()` -

Comment: @Rerito, see implementation of `kvfree()`.