# How to handle multiple pages buffers and scatterlists for Linux Crypto API?

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, cryptography

I am facing some trouble processing large buffers. Since I was testing my code only on quite small buffers (not larger than `PAGE_SIZE`), I have not met this before. The code is simply about ciphering or deciphering a buffer.

Currently, the code just sets one `scatterlist` object with the `sg_set_buf()` call for the source and the destination buffers. But it appears that, when doing things this simple, the encryption does not occur if the buffer size exceeds `PAGE_SIZE`.

Obviously, I can bypass the problem by allocating a smaller buffer, that fits in a single page and processing the larger buffer "progressively" with appropriate `memcpy()` calls. But since this is ugly, time and resource consuming ...

I was wondering if there was a way to handle nicely the `scatterlist` objects for this kind of buffers ?

**EDIT** : I forgot to say I already went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376825/linux-kernel-scatterlist-maximum-length-allowed).

---

**Other EDIT** : In fact, I have quite the same issue as [user173586](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376825/linux-kernel-scatterlist-maximum-length-allowed). The thing is, I cannot know in advance if the buffer handed to me is allocated with `vmalloc()` or `kmalloc()`.
To determine this, I just have to check whether the given address is in the range [`VMALLOC_START`, `VMALLOC_END`]. Once it is done, I have still to set up the `scatterlist` objects nicely  - here is the hard part -.

I know I can retrieve the page corresponding to a `vmalloc()`-ed buffer with `vmalloc_to_page()`. At this point, I have a `struct page` object corresponding to the address I gave. **I do not know how I can get the offset in the corresponding page.**

How can I know the `page` object "validity" ? I mean which area of the page is actually used by the `vmalloc()`-ed buffer. At first glance, it seems I need to retrieve each page used for the buffer and set up a `scatterlist` entry for it but I have no idea on how I should do that.

*(Any insight on the inner `vmalloc()` functioning can help. My current knowledge about this can be inferred from [this article](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-4))*

Answer (score 0):

The key is that kmalloc will always return space in physically continuous pages but vmalloc will not. You can detect the kmalloc'd buffer with virt_addr_valid. If that fails, you have to iterate through all the pages in the buffer and create separate scatterlist entries. You can see an example by looking at [this recent commit](https://github.com/kohler/click/pull/90) to [click](https://github.com/kohler/click/), though this code reuses the same, single scatterlist. It is also possible to allocate (len/PAGE_SIZE) + 1 scatterlists (the last one might not actually get used) and fill them out the same way.